# what is the lifecyle of a package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm writing a package and I have questions. With this package, I can manage the theme of the application, but after putting the application in the background and spending time in different applications, when I return to the my application, I see that the state of the package is lost.

Can a singleton class inside a package lose its data after the application is backgrounded?

Is there any behavior that can cause a package class and the class inside the application to behave differently?

what is the lifecyle of a package in dart?

Comment: Hello
Did you check the whole app loses its data or only the parts related to the package ?

Comment: Hi @Steve, app working correctly but only package parts fail. And if I didn't use other apps(I mean if I swap fastly) ex: ıf I wasn't open the browser, fastly return to the app, package is working correctyle.